# I downloaded an audiobook in .aax format from audible.com but it is invisible in Windows

Tags: audible

I see the file in recent files and I can click to open its directory. However the actual directory does not list the file.

It is not a hidden file either.

Comment: Is it possible to download it again?

Comment: Has your AV quarantined it?